# Linq to Entities parameterless constructor requirement ruins potential for lazy querying

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects, lazy-evaluation

So, the internet has been telling me that, in order to create a Linq to Entities query that returns a bunch of objects, (tuples, for instance) that query must actually be broken into client and server steps (Linq to Entities and Linq to Objects). Something about making code more maintainable. For instance,

```
    (
        from table 
        select Tuple.Create(a, b)
    );
```

is illegal, and must actually be written as

```
    (
        from table 
        select new {A=a, B=b}
    ).ToList().Select(row => Tuple.Create(row.A, row.B));
```

However, as soon as we call ToList(), the query is run and fully enumerated, killing the great potential for lazy loading. I realize that you can circumvent this with classes which have settable properties, but what about system classes that shouldn't be duplicated, or custom classes with complicated logic in the constructors? Is there any **simple** way to circumvent this restriction, so that the creation of objects can be queued up, only to be performed when the IQueryable collection is enumerated?

Feel free to let me know if what I'm trying to do indicates a "poor" design as well, but it would be nice to know if this is at least possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuple is an **off case** since it doesn't have constructors or fields that you can set.

If you create your own objects, you can use field initializers as you'd expect:

```
from table
select new MyTuple() { A = a, B = b };
```

I didn't know it, but it looks like Entities just doesn't recognize a function call as a creation method.

Comment: When I write a query like the first example you gave, I get the following runtime exception:  "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities"

Comment: My bad.  I thought example one was valid.  Ok, but I know example two works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of Entities are you using?